# Android set camera2 focus only once on beginning of timelapse

Tags: android, android-camera2, camera2

I want to make simple app that is making captures for timelapse. Finally I have made it. But I am wondering whether it is possible to lock focus only once, on first photo? And later use that saved value about focus (if possible)? Generally it is a good idea? I thought that every several seconds calling `lockFocus()` is too expensive. While device is placed fixed, motionless.

Actually I have code like to google sample code. I am setting `CaptureRequest.Builder` field `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER` to `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START` and in `CaptureCallback` I am checking for `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE`, if `ok` then capture final photo. Maybe get in first photo the `LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE` and later somehow set this value.

PS: Additionally I don't show preview to user and whole camera logic is running in Service and in other thread. Also I have implemented `ImageReader` and more.

My code is:

```
// before is `CameraManager`, setting outputs, opening camera - all ok

public void makePhoto() { // this I call from outer 
// plus some observer, not important conditions for this issue

createCameraPreviewSession();
}

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            mCaptureSession = session;
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();

            startedRepeatedRequest = false; // simple flag to start lockFocus after below request has started, once
            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, null);
        }
    }
}


private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        if(!startedRepeatedRequest) {
            // this is called only once, on the beginning of session
            lockFocus();
            startedRepeatedRequest = true;
        }

        switch(mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW:
                break;
            case STATE_WAITING_LOCK:
                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if (afState == null) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState || CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture(); // this leads to final capture photo
                    } else {
                        runPrecaptureSequence();
                    }
                }
                break;
            // There are also flags for STATE_PRECAPTURE, and STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE but this doesn't matter here
        }
    }
}

private void lockFocus() {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
}

private void captureStillPicture() {
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    Surface surfaceTarget = mImageReader.getSurface();
    captureBuilder.addTarget(surfaceTarget);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte) 90);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

    // callback for final capture
    CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
        mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        session.close();
    }

    mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
    mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
}
```

Comment: You simply need to call lockfocus once you have settuped the camera preview and donot release it untill the capturing done. Important thing is that call lockfocus and unlockfocus both must not be called twice. Remove lockfocus from process method too

Comment: Sorry for so long time to reply. You mind lock&unlock for single capture ofcourse? No - lock, capture, capture.., unlock? Probably so. So If I want to capture very fast I should use video recording.

Comment: @user2209414 How did you solve this?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal I gave up. I stopped caring so much. This project was just hobby app. Generally I call focus procedure every photo. I was too lazy to investigate this more.