# How to lock focus in camera2 api, android?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to lock focus after my custom camera finds focus.
First it AF mode set to auto:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
```

And After touching the preview it finds focus distance, and I have to lock AF and AE using this code:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
```

Locking AE works fine in any devices. Locking AF is working on Nexus5 and Nexus 5x. But as for Samsung S5 and S6, it keeps try to search focus.

What is the best way to lock focus?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order to lock the AF you have to take care of requesting the `AF_TRIGGER` only once by using `capture()` instead of `repeatingRequest()` (if not it enters in an af request loop and remains always trying to focus, but some nexus fix this in its FW, so some devices as `Nexus 5` focus well even it shouldn't)

So, the correct order will be:

- Set `CONTROL_AF_MODE` to `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` (via `session.setRepeatingRequest()`) and the `AF_REGIONS` and the `AE_REGIONS` if you want
- Wait until you check that the `CONTROL_AF_MODE` is already in auto by checking the `totalCaptureRequest` from the `CaptureCallback`.
- Set the `AF_TRIGGER_START` in the builder along with the `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO`but this time instead of using `session.setRepeatingRequest()` use `session.capture()`.
- Inmediately after that, set the `AF_TRIGGER` to set the `AF_TRIGGER_IDLE` (not cancel!) an use again `session.setRepeatingRequest()` along with the `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO`.
- Wait until it has focused,you will receive `FOCUSED_LOCKED` or `NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED`.

The `PASSIVE_FOCUSED` state is only when the `CONTROL_AF_MODE` is in continuous picture not in auto!

Take care of being really in auto focus mode before performing the trigger.

You should use always `session.capture()` with all triggers (with `CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER` too) but always after that remember to put the triggers to `IDLE` (not cancel) in a `session.repeatingRequest()`

Comment: Very awesome explanation! Thank you.

Comment: It would be really great if you take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090124/searching-focus-keeps-failing-with-external-lens-camera2-api-in-android

Comment: Mmm, sorry I have not worked with any external lens, I can not help you :(

Comment: In this what you mean by "Wait until you check that the CONTROL_AF_MODE is already in auto by checking the totalCaptureRequest from the CaptureCallback." @Yamidragut

Comment: When you do the `session.setRepeatingRequest()`, the second parameter is a `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`. You have to create one and in the `onCaptureCompleted()` callback you obtain a `TotalCaptureResult`. Then you can process that `TotalCaptureResult` to obtain different kind of info such as the `AF_MODE` or the current `AE_STATE` among many others. 
For example, you can retrieve the current `AF_MODE` by calling to `result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_MODE)`. 
Take into account that some of the values can be null in some frames depending on the device, so check always nullability

Comment: @Yamidragut Can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128863/android-set-camera2-focus-only-once-on-beginning-of-timelapse?

Answer (score 5):

You can't locus the focus on `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`.

You should put your AF mode on `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` adn wait for `FOCUSED_LOCKED` state during your AF trigger. You can check how the Android focus machine works on [enter link description here](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_3Amodes.html)

Comment: Yes I am also doing same. First it is `CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO `, and wait until AF state is `FOCUSED_LOCKED` or `PASSIVE_FOCUSED`. And then I set AF trigger to `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL`, AF mode to `CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE ` for Nexus, `CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF` to Samsung s5/s6

Comment: But I am not sure which is proper way, because it is acting different device to device.

Comment: If I set to `CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF `, it is working well for Samsung. But in Nexus5/5x it becomes blurry

Comment: Samsung devices as their own Firmware to work together with the camera API, if you want to see how their work you should check their custom camera implementation: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera

Comment: I see, then the way checking device model is normal?

Comment: Each firmware is different, and the companies usually change the way their HAL(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)) works to make easier the implementation on the application level. But that also causes problems when other's want to work with a public `API` like `camera2` in their devices.

I suggest you to make your app based on the `hardware capabilities` that you retrieve using `CameraCharacteristics`, and try to implement as little as possible "checking device" condition, because each device update can change the way about how it works. But the hardware not.

Comment: I got it. Thank you! I will try to make it.

Comment: Check the answer from Yamidragut, I think that he deserve more the right answer to this question.