# How to lock camera focus at point where i have clicked photo in camera2 api

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I know this kind of question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127464/how-to-lock-focus-in-camera2-api-android) .But i was unable to understand what should i do in my case. So what I want to do is to show clicked photo and stop camera preview whenever i click photos and whenever camera button is pressed again i want to show preview again. Here is how i am taking photo

```
private void takePhoto() {
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder request = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        request.addTarget(jpegSurface);
        request.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_LENS_SHADING_MAP_MODE, CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_LENS_SHADING_MAP_MODE_ON);

        imageCaptured = true;
        lockFocus();
        session.capture(request.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "captured..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {
                unLockFocus();
                imageCaptured=false;
            }
        }, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to click photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

and here is code for preview

```
 private void startCamera() {
    try {
        requestPreview = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        requestPreview.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        requestPreview.addTarget(textureSurface);
        session.setRepeatingRequest(requestPreview.build(), null, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to create preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

and here is how i am locking and unlocking focus

```
    private void lockFocus() {
    requestPreview.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
    try {
        session.capture(requestPreview.build(), null, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void unLockFocus() {
    scanButton.setText("SCAN");
    imageCaptured = false;
    requestPreview.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
    try {
        session.setRepeatingRequest(requestPreview.build(), null, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (imageCaptured) {
                unLockFocus();
                return;
            }
            takePhoto();
        }
    });
```

But problem with this code is that it lock focus for few second and then camera preview starts again. this might be happening because of `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START` and `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL`. If this is the reason then what can i use instead of this.

Comment: on which cell phone you're testing?

Comment: Lyf mobiles....